# Apache POI: Add elements to a cell using XWPFTableCell addParagraph(XWPFParagraph)

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I wanted all the existing body elements read from a document to be written into a table cell. Here's the code. Though the sysout writes the element text, the paragraphs are not getting added to the cell.

```
public static void insertElementsToTableCell(XWPFTableCell cell, List<IBodyElement> elements)
{
    for (Integer n = 0; n < elements.size(); n++)
    {
        IBodyElement element = elements.get(n);
        if (element instanceof XWPFParagraph)
        {
            cell.addParagraph((XWPFParagraph) element);
            System.out.println(((XWPFParagraph) element).getParagraphText());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear why the `void addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p)` is public at all since it works only in combination with `public XWPFParagraph addParagraph()` because only the latter will adding the paragrap's `XML` to the cell's `XML`.  The `addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p)` only adds the paragraph to the internal list of paragraphs of the cell but does not change the `XML` in any way.

Look at [XWPFTableCell.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.java?revision=1791046&view=markup#l148) to see that.

We could at first create a new `XWPFParagraph` added to the cell's `CTTc` and then using `addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p)`  with this new paragraph. But then we can also using only the low level elements at all.

Nevertheless we should add the paragraph to the internal list of paragraphs of the cell in case we later needs to work with the list of paragraphs in the cell via `cell.getParagraphs()`.

But the `public void addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p)` lacks updating the `protected List<IBodyElement> bodyElements`. So `public List<IBodyElement> getBodyElements()` will be wrong after adding paragraphs to the cell. But this is true also after adding empty paragraphs using `public XWPFParagraph addParagraph()`. And there is not a usable method provided in `XWPFTableCell` to correct this.

```
 public static void insertElementsToTableCell(XWPFTableCell cell, List<IBodyElement> elements) {
  for (IBodyElement element :  elements) {
   if (element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph) element;
    cell.getCTTc().getPList().add(paragraph.getCTP());
    //System.out.println(cell.getCTTc());
    cell.addParagraph(paragraph);
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. In fact, found that cell.addParagraph(paragraph); didn't do anything. Commenting the line out does the same thing.

Comment: @Vijai: The `cell.addParagraph(paragraph)` adds the paragraph to the internal list of paragraphs of the cell. Without using it the  `List` gotten from `cell.getParagraphs()` will not contain that paragraph.

Comment: table is getting looped